# sudo to different user and run commands immediately post sudo, passively (non interactively )

Tags: bash, shell, path, ksh, sudo

Consider this sudo - I am logged in as jonhnd and   run this through  a script run1st.ksh that has the below command

```
sudo -iu bigadmin
```

This elevates my credentials to bigadmin a generic user but that user is a 'shared' user meaning - I really dont have any leeway to customize his personal profile
After he is logged in ,I see his PATH variable is very skinny ,with just few paths added

```
echo $PATH 
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin
```

so the pwd is not in the path and neither would be executable . No of those dir's in the $PATH is writable and  like I said modifying any personal files of bigadmin isn't an option.  I have a start up script I execute as that user for just my sessions and I have to force execute it

```
. ./myscript
```

will work

```
myscript 
. myscript
```

gives myscript not found error understandably because the path restrictions mentioned above.
What I want to do is this run the sudo and myscript in run1st.ksh so that when I enter that bigadmin prompt myscript has  already run 
@barmar
thanks for helping .
here is the o/p from running that ( put verbose on set -x )

```
++ sudo -iu bigadmin ksh -c '. ./run1st.ksh'
Usage: . [ options ] name [arg ...]
```

@Barmar

```
sudo -iu bigadmin ksh -c '/home/bigadmin/run1st.ksh'
ksh: line 1: /home/bigadmin/run1st.ksh: not found

sudo -iu bigadmin ksh -c '. /home/biadmin/run1st.ksh'


age: . [ options ] name [arg ...]


$ sudo -iu bigadmin  ksh -c '. /home/bigadmin; run1st.ksh'
+ sudo -iu bigadmin ksh -c '. /home/bigadmin; run1st.ksh'
Usage: . [ options ] name [arg ...]

$ sudo -iu bigadmin  ksh -c '. /home/bigadmin/run1st.ksh ; run1st.ksh'
+ sudo -iu bigadmin ksh -c '. /home/bigadmin/run1st.ksh ; run1st.ksh'
Usage: . [ options ] name [arg ...]
```

does not work

```
$ sudo -iu bigadmin  /home/bigadmin/run1st.ksh
+ sudo -iu bigadmin /home/bigadmin/run1st.ksh
-nologin: line 1: /home/bigadmin/run1st.ksh: not found
```

It actually look for the run1st.ksh in johnd 's directory

```
$ sudo -iu bigadmin  echo `pwd`
++ pwd
+ sudo -iu bigadmin echo /home/johnd
```

and even after copying it  to johnd 's home- I get the SAME File not found command . So its looking for the file in specific PATH and not in the directory you put forth .  Maybe tweak PATH in that sudo command ?

there was a space in the filename `xxx. ksh` that I did'nt notice. Fixed that and now it does not give file not found error BUT it executes it and returns back to the johnd prompt.

```
$ sudo -iu bigadmin /home/bigadmin/run1st.ksh
+ sudo -iu bigadmin /home/bigadmin/run1st.ksh
++ printf '\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007' johnd server400 '~'
$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
sudo -iu bigadmin /path/to/myscript
```

Comment: that will get me in the bash shell right . How do I do the same thing and dive in as bigadmin into ksh  ( bourne ) shell

Comment: use `ksh` instead of `bash`.

Comment: doesn't quite work with ksh . I will have updated the o/p in the question in  a min

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. `ksh` takes a `-c` option just like other shells do.

Comment: The `-i` option sets the current directory to `bigadmin`'s home directory. So you need to put the full path to the script if it's not in his homedir.

Comment: should I be running it like this '-c '. /path/to/myscript; myscript' because my `some command` is `myscript`

Comment: I thought `myscript` was a script that sets environment variables that you need to run some command.

Comment: If you just need to run a script in some other directory than bigadmin's home directory, you just need to give the full path.

Comment: does not work,prolly because its looking for the that file in the PATH variable ? see Q update

Comment: In your last command, you're running `pwd` in the original shell, not the sudo shell.

Comment: Where is the script actually located? Most of your error messages imply that you're just giving the wrong path to the script. `. /home/bigadmin` by itself makes no sense -- the argument to `.` is a script to source, not a directory.

Comment: PATH is not used when you execute a command by pathname, it's only used when you execute a command with no directory prefix.

Comment: script is located in `/home/johnd `as well as `/home/bigadmin`

Comment: If you just do `sudo -i bigadmin` and then type `/home/bigadmin/run1st.ksh`, does it work?

Comment: " the argument to . is a script to source, not a directory. " right on - and that is what I did here `sudo -iu bigadmin  /home/bigadmin/run1st.ksh` and it comes back not found IN-SPITE of being right there ..strange ?

Comment: there was a space in the filename `xxx. ksh` that I did'nt notice. Fixed that and now it does not give file not found error BUT it executes it and returns back to the johnd prompt.

Comment: What did you expect? `sudo` just executes the command and then returns.

Comment: I want to remain  logged in  as bigadmin after executing that script

Comment: `sudo -iu bigadmin` gets me to bigadmins prompt and keeps me there. I 'd like to do the same thing but also run that script . By the time I am on bigadmin prompt I should have ran the  run1st.ksh script - is what I was trying to do

Comment: I don't think there's a way to start an interactive shell and have it run a script before the prompt, other than the standard startup scripts like .profile and .kshrc.

Comment: sorry I had expected some  shell jugglery  would work around the .profile  stuff but apparently the .<yourscripts> are the only savior